# Detect thrashing on AWS Auto Scale Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

Sometimes if there are conditions that prevent the app from starting, say a bad config, the auto scaler will continue to start up instances one after the other.

Anybody know of a good way to alert on this?

Answer (score 0):

Most of our servers receive network traffic so we put a CloudWatch monitor on the NetworkIn metric.

I would suggest configuring the start-up script to Terminate/Shutdown the instance upon failure and sending an alert using CloudWatch custom metrics or any other service like NewRelic.

I don't think that there is a way to alert auto-scaling-group to stop spanning up instances. You could set the max instances limit and have an alert upon reaching this number.

Comment: Max would not help as these are not all active at the same time. The ASG keeps starting instances and when they don't pass the ELB health check before the grace period hits, ASG will kill the instance and start another.

Answer (score 0):

You could alert based on the CloudWatch metric:

```
Auto Scaling / Group Metrics / GroupTerminatingInstances
```

See the [doc page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/as-instance-monitoring.html) for more details